# Confusion in concept of same function

Tags: functions

In this question 
Let
$f(x) = \sin^{-1}(\sin(\tan x))$ and

$g(x) = \cos^{-1}(\sin(\sqrt{1-\tan^2 x}))$  are same function, then x belongs to ________.

What are 'same functions'? No idea how to proceed. 
Just a pinch of hint. No need to explain whole solution.

[image: Question]

[image: Solution]

Comment: $f=g$ if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine And the domains of $f$ and $g$ are the same.

Comment: Maple shows that they aren't the same function!

Comment: @Michael Hoppe: ah, yes, that doesn't typically make a difference in the theories I'm used to, but you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be pedantic here for a moment, because I think it helps to get at the answer to the question. Two mathematical objects are the "same" in general if they, as sets, are equal. "But not everything is a set!" you might say. And I'll say, "Yes, everything in math *is* a set." In particular, ordered pairs like $(a, b)$ can be defined by a set-theoretic construction; when you do so properly, it turns out that $(a, b) = (c, d)$ if and only if $a = c$ and $b = d$. Once you're proved that, you can forget the set theory, which is nice.

So what's a function? The definition I like says that it's an ordered triple

$f = (D, C, R)$

where $D$ is a set (called the "domain"), $C$ is a set (called the "codomain", or "range" in some books, but since this word is used for another thing as well, I prefer to avoid it), and a third set $R$ (called the "rule" or the "graph" or the "relation") with several properties.

1. $R \subset D \times C$
2. If $(d, c_1)$ and $(d, c_2)$ are in $R$, then $c_1 = c_2$.
3. For each $d \in D$, there is an element $c \in C$ such that $(d, c) \in R$.

Note that condition 2 says that for each $d \in D$, there is ONLY one element $c \in C$ such that $(d, c) \in R$. Because of this, we write $c = f(d)$.

So what's it mean for functions

$f = (C, D, R)$ and $g = (C', D', R')$ to be equal?

It means that $D = D'$, $C = C'$, and $R = R'$. Malice Vidrine's hint summarizes this last condition, although I would have said "$f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in D$" for that part.

Many mathematicians use a compact notation to describe functions precisely. It looks like this:

$f: X \rightarrow Y : x \mapsto  \text{ some expression involving $x$}.$

That's shorthand for

(a) the domain of $f$ is the set $X$

(b) the codomain of $f$ is the set $Y$, and

(c) The "rule" of $f$ is the set $\{ (x, \text{expression for x}) : x \in X\}$.

Two remarks on this notation:

1. It's often skipped, and folks write $f(x) = x^2$ to implicitly mean something like "$f$ is a function from the reals to the reals which squares numbers." To be more precise, they should write

$f : \Re \rightarrow \Re : x \mapsto x^2$

instead.

1. The expression used to describe the function $f$ is different from the function itself. For instance, the two descriptions

$f : \Re \rightarrow \Re : x \mapsto x^2$, and

$g : \Re \rightarrow \Re : x \mapsto x^2 + 1 - 1$

are descriptions of the same functions: the domains and codomains match, and the relations are identical sets, even though they're expressed differently.

Suppose we let $Q$ denote all the non-negative real numbers. Look at the three functions

$f_1 : \Re \rightarrow  \Re : x \mapsto x^2$

$f_2 : \Re \rightarrow Q : x \mapsto x^2$

$f_3 : Q \rightarrow Q : x \mapsto x^2$

Even though all three have the expression "$x^2$" in them, they are distinct: $f_1$ and $f_2$ have different codomains; $f_2$ and $f_3$ have different domains.

Does it matter? Yes. $f_1$, for instance, does not have an inverse function, because there's no $x \in \Re$ for which $x^2 = -6$, for example.  On the other hand, for $f_2$, every element of the codomain is $f(x)$ for some $x$ in the domain, so it *might* have an inverse function. But $f_2(-2) = f_2(2)$, so two different domain values map to the same codomain value, and there cannot be an inverse. $f_3$, on the third hand, is actually an invertible function, and we call its inverse the "square root."

So: when someone writes $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$, what are the intended domain and codomain? If you don't know that, you can't possibly determine whether $f$ is the same as some other function. The answer is, "You really can't be certain," alas, but as a matter of practice, the domain is usually implicitly regarded as the set of all $x \in \Re$ such that the expression makes sense. In this example, that means that $1 - x^2 \ge 0$ (so that it has a square root), so $-1 \le x \le 1$ is the implied domain.

For your first function ($f(x) = \arcsin(\sin(\tan(x)))$), the domain of $\tan$ is all of $\Re$; the codomain is all of $\Re$ as well, and that's within the domain of $\sin$, whose codomain is typically taken to be $[-1, 1]$, which is within the domain of arcsin. So I'd write

$f : \Re \rightarrow [-\pi/2, \pi/2] :  x \mapsto \arcsin(\sin(\tan x))$.

For your second function, what is the implied domain? Well, the tangent has all of $\Re$ as its domain, but for values outside $[-\pi/4, \pi/4]$, we'll have $1 - \tan^2(x) < 0$. So the domain can be no larger than $[-\pi/4, \pi/4]$.

You can work through the rest of the function $g$ to see if there are other implied constraints on the domain.

My natural answer to this question would be "the domains of $f$ and $g$ are different, so they're not the same function." But I think that the goal pof the question here is to say "what's the largest domain on which these two functions agree?" The answer will therefore be, at the very least, no larger than $[-\pi/4, \pi/4]$.

Since the functions you've given us don't even agree at 0 (i.e., $f(0) \ne g(0)$, I have the suspicion that maybe there's a typo somewhere, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: You have too much time to spare.

Comment: Thanks,  your explanation for same function is much better than the highly technical explanation in my book. I worked on the question based on your explanation and got the same result,  but that's not what my book says.  I have uploaded the pictures of the question and it's solution(went through my head) from the book, can you take a look at it.

Comment: The second line of what your book says, where $cos(tan(x))$ turns into $\sin(\sqrt{1-\tan^2(x)})$, is just plain wrong. If you test out the alleged equality for $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$, you have $\tan(x) = 1$, and the equality alleges that $\cos(1) = \sin(0)$, which is false.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe: I have time enough to teach; it happens to be my job.